# How can I check if the data is coming in is string delimited or JSON?

Tags: php, json, delimiter

Let's say I have a variable $data['media']; 
The problem is the data might be either look like a string so for example

```
$data['media'] = '1|BlahBLah2|0'
```

or it might come in as json encoded string such as

```
$data['media'] = '{"site_id":"1","string":"BlahBlah2","cool":"0"}';
```

What is the best way to distinguish if it's a delimited string or json encoded string?

Comment: will the delimited string ever start with `{` or `[` ?

Comment: json_decode(), trap for error (ie. a NULL return)... if there's an error, then it is a string... only problematic if the JSON actually was a NULL

Comment: Is there no way make your program deterministic, i.e., so that you *know* which format to expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_decode` will return decoded data or `NULL` if it's not json data, so you could use something like this:

```
$decode = json_decode($data['media']);

if ($decode)
{
    // the data was json encoded, so now we can process it
    $data['media'] = $decode;
}
else // data is a string
```

Comment: This will fail for JSON values of `false`, `true` and `null`, which are sent as strings, without the encircling braces. (Of course, whether the end result is any different will depend on how the data is handled by the script, but `NULL!="NULL"`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
if( json_decode( $data['media'] )!==NULL || strtolower( $data['media'] )=='null' )
{
  $data['media'] = json_decode( $data['media'] );
}
else
{
  # Not a JSON string
}
```